# How to add options to the notification in a MAUI android application?

Tags: c#, maui

I am following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications

But I don't see the option to add actions to the notification.

In some examples, at the button of the notification, I can see some text that for example "go forward" and when it is clicked, an action is performed.

I know that when I create a notification, I can set an action with .SetActions(MyMethodAction()) and then implement the method with the logic:

```
private Notification.Action MyMthodAction()
{
    //do somethig
}
```

But I don't know how to implement the method.

How could add actions to a notification in MAUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how to implement the method.

I did a test on the official sample [localnotifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/localnotifications/),and added  `AddAction` to the local notification. It works fine on myside.

You can refer to the following code:

```
void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) 
        {
            // Pass the current button press count value to the next activity:
            var valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
            valuesForActivity.PutInt(COUNT_KEY, count);

            // When the user clicks the notification, SecondActivity will start up.
            var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));

            // Pass some values to SecondActivity:
            resultIntent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity);

            // Construct a back stack for cross-task navigation:
            var stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
            stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Class.FromType(typeof(SecondActivity)));
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

            // Create the PendingIntent with the back stack:            
           // var resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int) PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)

                ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Mutable

                : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;

            var resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)pendingIntentFlags);


            // Build the notification:
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
                         // .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                          .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
                          .SetNumber(count) // Display the count in the Content Info
                         
                          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click) // This is the icon to display
                          .SetContentText($"The button has been clicked {count} times.")
                          .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.user,"test", resultPendingIntent); // the message to display.

            // Finally, publish the notification:
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());

            // Increment the button press count:
            count++;
        }
```

Note:

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` or `FLAG_MUTABLE` be specified when creating a PendingIntent. So I also added `PendingIntentFlags.Mutable` for the intent.

Comment: Hi @Álvaro García, I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: Hi @jessie, how can we pass a MAUI shell page (or route) instead of android activities?